# set global ( module level ) interceptor in nestjs/ axios HttpModule

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

how can I add an interceptor for logging outgoing requests?
I know I can add it per instance of HttpService like this:

```
this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use((config) => ...)
```

But I want to add it once, that's why I'm asking if there's a way to add it at the module level - I saw there is an option to add configuration to the module like this:

```
imports: [HttpModule.register({...})]
```

there is anyone knows how can I config the interceptor this way?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As a variant, you can use this example to write your own *HttpModule* which will take Axios *HttpSerive*.
To use `register` \ `registerAsync` you need to `extends` your module from Axios *HttpModule* (on the example `AxiosHttpModule`)

```js
import { HttpModule as AxiosHttpModule, HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Global, Inject, Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';

import { Logger } from '@app/common/Logger';
import {
  createReqInterceptor,
  createRespFailInterceptor,
  createRespSuccessInterceptor,
} from '@app/common/http/http.interceptors';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [AxiosHttpModule],
  exports: [AxiosHttpModule],
})
export class HttpModule extends AxiosHttpModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public onModuleInit(): any {
    const axios = this.httpService.axiosRef;

    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config: AxiosRequestConfig) {
     //... some logic
    });
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response: AxiosResponse) {
       //... some logic
      },
      function (err: AxiosError) {
        //... some logic
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*TLTR*: Also, you need to notice that `HttpModule.register()` will create a new instance each time - so you can't make some logic global at `AppModule` initiation - it was the easiest way to use middleware at `configure`:

```
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(RequestsMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
```