# How to get headers from AxiosResponse-Observable?

Tags: axios, rxjs, nestjs

Using NestJS, Axios returns an `Observable<AxiosResponse>`.

How can I get the headers of a GET- or HEAD-Request?

Lets say I make a HEAD-request:

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

const observable = this.httpService.head(uri);
```

How can I get the headers from the result?

---

**Update:**

I found a nice workaround that just works with a single line of code.

There is another library called `https` with is more powerful:

```
import http from "https";

await http.request(uri, { method: 'HEAD' }, (res) => {
  console.log(res.headers);
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
}).end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers of the response are available in the `subscribe` callback with the `headers` property.

```js
this.httpService.head(uri).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.headers)
});
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgCRjMBlAplAbsAYyzgF84AzKCEOAcgAEA7LAZxgCsWB6AQwA9gEFrQDcAKDEATLAQA2PKMQIRGbOAAs0mHPiIAuFFux5CWCZvTHdWAHTqsPSQAoARBbB6uXAOYQI32VtlEBcAShsWAFcAIxYCKGBorCdFFjgAXgA+RDE4PLhlVQhAm1l-FNY7B2koFlCxElCRIA)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config:

For request headers you should use something like this:

```
this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
console.log(config);
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

You should use it onModuleInit (to prevent working a few interceptors in a time)

Also you can make own module like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72543771/4546382

For the response headers you can just use response.headers